# Issue in finding email id from a string - Python

Tags: python, regex, email

Can somebody help me figure out what is the issue with the below code:

```
import re

class RegexTest(object):
    
    def regex_test(self, reg, string):
        reg_pattern = repr(reg)[1:-1]
        match = re.search(reg_pattern, string)
        if (match is not None):
            return match.group(0)
        else:
            return None
        
test = RegexTest()
print(test.regex_test('[A-Za-z0-9\._]+\@\w+\.\w{2,4}', 'My email id is: abcd123_hello@yahoo.com'))
```

Output:

```
None
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `reg_pattern = repr(reg)[1:-1]`, use `match = re.search(reg, string)`

Comment: Hello Mahesh_Vkm, welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to explain what your code is supposed to do, and how it differs from the actual result. Users will appreciate if they do not have to reconstruct this from only your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the regex pattern you create inside `regex_test` method, you will see you are not using the literal string pattern itself, but a string literal converted to literal text. That means, all backslashes become doubled in the pattern, and a `\\` in a regex pattern matches a literal `\` char.

Look:

```
print(repr(reg)[1:-1])
# => [A-Za-z0-9\\._]+\\@\\w+\\.\\w{2,4}
print(reg)
# => [A-Za-z0-9\._]+\@\w+\.\w{2,4}
```

Use

```
def regex_test(self, reg, string):
    match = re.search(reg, string)
    if match is not None:
        return match.group(0)
    else:
        return None
```

You do not need to wrap the `if` condition with parentheses.

When defining a pattern, it is recommended to use a raw string literal and you do not need to escape `.` inside a character class and a `@` char:

```
print(test.regex_test(r'[A-Za-z0-9._]+@\w+\.\w{2,4}', 'My email id is: abcd123_hello@yahoo.com'))
```